# some corrupty graphics in 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics, visual-artifacts

I got 14.04 LTS (because Xenial WHY NO AMD?!?) and it worked flawlessly (process going fine and stuff) and when I boot it.... some stripes of glitcheyness happens and then normal boot..

If anyone can tell me some suggestions or answers, that will be appreciated.

(I'm using ATI graphics BTW)

But during normal use, short rainbows, more stripes in applications occur.

TEMP CHATROOM HERE: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/42809/discussion-of-editys-sore-ati-graphics-problem?tab=general

Comment: Do the stripes go away? Are they just displayed for a moment or two during boot?

Comment: They appear somewhat in the boot process and in the boot (onky for a short time.)

Comment: NO THIS IS NOT A GRAPHICS PROBLEM. i examined the card carefully and no problem there.

Comment: I will make a chat, so hop on if you have suggestions

Comment: This is where the original poster made the chat room: [Discussion of Edity's sore ATI graphics problem](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42809/discussion-of-editys-sore-ati-graphics-problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necropost 2 years later!

Solved with PC upgrade.

Thanks everyone!